# SqlDataAdapter doesn't delete a record

Tags: c#, sql

I use `DataSet` to store data and `SqlDataAdapter` to work with database.

for change records in DataBase first I edit rows (insert,Edit,delete) DataTable in Dataset ..

then

```
DataRow dr = DataSetMain.Tables["tbl_error"].Select("error_name='" + error.Name + "'")[0];
            DataSetMain.Tables["tbl_error"].Rows.Remove(dr);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_error", SVariable._DataBaseConnectionString);
                SqlCommandBuilder bui = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);
    adp.Update(DataSetName,tbl_error);
```

**for insert or edit record every thing work like a charm** ...
but for delete it does not work ..

I`m sure row in tbl_error successfully deleted but adp.Update it won't delete anything from the database ...

how i can find problem ?

Comment: Do you get a error or does the Update complete without error but the rows are still there?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : NO.
dr.delete() solved my problem .. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling Rows.Remove() is equivalent to call Rows.Delete() + AcceptChanges().
Due to AcceptChanges, Update() don't do any modification.

Then replace:

```
DataSetMain.Tables["tbl_error"].Rows.Remove(dr);
```

by

```
dr.Delete()
```